# Make a sticky menu in CSS and JS WITHOUT Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css, sticky

I'm building a small personal website and would like to know how to make a sticky menu in HTML/CSS And JS without using JQuery (because I don't want to include it for such a small use)  [like this one](http://www.outyear.co.uk/smint/demo/)

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried anything, written any code?  If so please post it.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume with 'sticky' you mean a mean staying on top (over) your content and being visible regardless of view port (scrolling state). This can be done by using `position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; with: 100%` on the menu's container. The important thing is `position: fixed`; it makes sure the menu stays where it is...

Did I guessed this correct?

Comment: I did take a look at this. But it seems as if my platform is not well supported -- the responsive site looked quiet odd and there was no sticky menu... So what's more?